# How to filter vector of maps by multiple keys in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure, clojurescript

Assume we have a datastructure like this one:

```
(def data
     (atom [{:id 1 :first-name "John1" :last-name "Dow1" :age "14"}
            {:id 2 :first-name "John2" :last-name "Dow2" :age "54"}
            {:id 3 :first-name "John3" :last-name "Dow3" :age "34"}
            {:id 4 :first-name "John4" :last-name "Dow4" :age "12"}
            {:id 5 :first-name "John5" :last-name "Dow5" :age "24"}]))
```

I have learned how to filter it by one key, for example:

```
(defn my-filter
  [str-input]
  (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                         (lower-case)
                         (re-pattern))
                         (lower-case (:first-name %)))
            @data))

> (my-filter "John1")
> ({:last-name "Dow1", :age "14", :first-name "John1", :id 1})
```

But now I'm a little bit confused on how to filter data by `:first-name`, `:last-name` and `:age` simple way?
**Update**: Sorry for being not too clear enough in explanation of what the problem is... Actually, I want all keys `:first-name`, `:last-name` and `:age` to paticipate in filter function, so that, if `str-input` doesn't match `:first-name`'s val, check if it matches `:last-name`'s val and so on.

**Update 2**:
After trying `some-fn`, `every-pred` and `transducers`, I didn't get what I need, e.g. regex in filter predicates, I guess it's a lack of knowledge for now.
So, I ended up with this function which works fine, but the code is ugly and duplicated. How I can get rid of code duplication?

```
(defn my-filter [str-input]
  (let [firstname (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                         (upper-case)
                                         (re-pattern))
                                    (upper-case (:first-name %)))
                     @data)
        lastname (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                        (upper-case)
                                        (re-pattern))
                                   (upper-case (:last-name %)))
                    @data)
        age (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                   (upper-case)
                                   (re-pattern))
                              (upper-case (:age %)))
               @data)]
    (if-not (empty? firstname)
      firstname
      (if-not (empty? lastname)
        lastname
        (if-not (empty? age)
          age)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be achieved with the help of functional composition, e.g. you can use `every-pred` function, which creates a function, checking if all the preds are truthy for its arguments, and use it to filter data. For example if you want to find all items with odd `:id` value having `:last-name` of `"Dow1", "Dow2",` or `"Dow3"` and `:age` starting with `\3`:

```
user> (def data
  [{:id 1 :first-name "John1" :last-name "Dow1" :age "14"}
   {:id 2 :first-name "John2" :last-name "Dow2" :age "54"}
   {:id 3 :first-name "John3" :last-name "Dow3" :age "34"}
   {:id 4 :first-name "John4" :last-name "Dow4" :age "12"}
   {:id 5 :first-name "John5" :last-name "Dow5" :age "24"}])

user> (filter (every-pred (comp odd? :id)
                          (comp #{"Dow1" "Dow2" "Dow3"} :last-name)
                          (comp #{\3} first :age))
              data)

;;=> ({:id 3, :first-name "John3", :last-name "Dow3", :age "34"})
```

another way to do it, is to use [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers):

```
user> (sequence (comp (filter (comp odd? :id))
                      (filter (comp #{"Dow1" "Dow2" "Dow3"} :last-name)))
                data)
```

notice that the actual filtering would happen just once for every item, so it won't create any intermediate collections.

**Update**

According to your update you need to keep the value when *any* of the predicates is true, so you can use `some` function instead of `every-pred`:

```
user> (filter #(some (fn [pred] (pred %))
                     [(comp odd? :id)
                      (comp #{"Dow1" "Dow2" "Dow4"} :last-name)
                      (comp (partial = \3) first :age)])
              data)
;;=> ({:id 1, :first-name "John1", :last-name "Dow1", :age "14"} {:id 2, :first-name "John2", :last-name "Dow2", :age "54"} {:id 3, :first-name "John3", :last-name "Dow3", :age "34"} {:id 4, :first-name "John4", :last-name "Dow4", :age "12"} {:id 5, :first-name "John5", :last-name "Dow5", :age "24"})
```

Comment: The "or" counterpart to `every-pred` is `some-fn`. You can just switch them around in your first example, no need to use `some`.

Comment: @leetwinski, could you please check second update? thanks

Comment: i guess it is better to make up another question of it, because it is about the topic, which is different from initial question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would just work for you. Using the fact that in Clojure :first-name is a function that can be used to look up its corresponding value in a hashmap.

```
(defn find-all 
  [field value data] 
  (filter #(= value (field %)) data))
```

This will return a list of the matching hashmaps in your vector.

```
user=> (find-all :first-name "John1" @data)
({:id 1, :first-name "John1", :last-name "Dow1", :age "14"})
```

I would suggest you to store age as integer instead of string if you do not have a strong case not to.

More about keywords:

**(:key map)**

- works when your map is nil

> ```
> user=> (:key-word nil)
> nil
> ```

- can be used with map or filter

> ```
> user=> (map :last-name @data)
> ("Dow1" "Dow2" "Dow3" "Dow4" "Dow5")
> ```

- :key cannot be nil

> ```
> user=> (nil (first @data))
> CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call nil, form: (nil (first (clojure.core/deref data))),
> ```
>
> compiling:(/private/var/folders/nr/g50ld9t91c555dzv91n43bg40000gn/T/form-init5403593628725666667.clj:1:1)

**(map :key)**

- better when :key is nil

> ```
> user=> ((first @data) nil)
> nil
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry for being not too clear enough in explanation of what the problem is... Could you, please, check an updated question?! Thanks.