# Filter on the values of multiple keys in a map entry and return a map with those entries Clojure

Tags: filter, clojure, clojurescript

I am new to clojure and need some help.

In clojurescript I build up a html table using a map (stored in atom) e.g.

```
[{:id 2, :category "Big bang theory", :name "The Big Bang!"} 
{:id 3, :category "The big Lebowski", :name "Ethan Coen"}
{:id 4, :category "Chitty Chitty Bang Bang", :name "Roald Dahl"}]
```

I want to create a search that searches for a word (i.e. "ban") en return a map with those entries that have that word (or part of it) in one of its key values.

In case of "ban" it should return

```
[{:id 2, :category "Big bang theory", :name "The Big Bang!"} 
{:id 4, :category "Chitty Chitty Bang Bang", :name "Roald Dahl"}]
```

Based on the above map the table updates with only those two entries.

I found some interesting solutions, but they all focus on one key (i.e. :category or :name) but not all keys in the map entry.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643091/how-to-filter-vector-of-maps-by-multiple-keys-in-clojure) tries to achieve the same, but I don't think someone gave the answer. Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(def maps
  [{:id 2, :category "Big bang theory", :name "The Big Bang!"}
   {:id 3, :category "The big Lebowski", :name "Ethan Coen"}
   {:id 4, :category "Chitty Chitty Bang Bang", :name "Roald Dahl"}])

(filter
 #(some
   (fn [v]
     (when (string? v)
       (-> v
           (str/lower-case)
           (str/includes? "ban"))))
   (vals %))
 maps)
```

Comment: From this, I learned that clojure.string/lower-case calls .toString first. Cheers!

Comment: @dpassen FWIW, it is not legal to pass an integer to `clojure.string/lower-case`. See the docstring for the `clojure.string` namespace for more info. The behavior is undefined Clojure as is also the case in ClojureScript (where it throws).

Comment: @MikeFikes The type hint gives it away, as well.

Comment: Whoops, only tested in a Clojure REPL. Fixed now :).